# UFW + fail2ban not working with `nginx` to block attack scripts

Tags: ipv6, cname-record, fail2ban, ufw

my server is currently attacked by some script kiddies. I have set up `fail2ban` which correctly bans the IP.

```
2020-01-07 05:51:45,639 fail2ban.actions        [1656]: WARNING [nginx-botsearch] 123.207.92.128 already banned
2020-01-07 05:51:47,802 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:47
2020-01-07 05:51:48,026 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:48
2020-01-07 05:51:48,242 fail2ban.actions        [1656]: WARNING [nginx-botsearch] 123.207.92.128 already banned
2020-01-07 05:51:49,228 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:49

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY IN     123.207.92.128
```

Which is the **first** rule

```
2020-01-07 05:51:45,639 fail2ban.actions        [1656]: WARNING [nginx-botsearch] 123.207.92.128 already banned
2020-01-07 05:51:47,802 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:47
2020-01-07 05:51:48,026 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:48
2020-01-07 05:51:48,242 fail2ban.actions        [1656]: WARNING [nginx-botsearch] 123.207.92.128 already banned
2020-01-07 05:51:49,228 fail2ban.filter         [1656]: INFO    [nginx-botsearch] Found 123.207.92.128 - 2020-01-07 05:51:49
```

But as you see the IP is already banned and the attacker still can access.

I wonder how this is possible?

I tested this for my local net and found out that I can still access the **domain** but not the IP. I think thats because it uses IPv6 then. But why I don't get an IPv6 log entry then?

My domain is set up using CNAME. Does that mather? I don't know if the attacker knows the domain but he might be forwarded to it.

Comment: You mention IPv6 in the title, but there are only IPv4 addresses in the question. Did you redact them? Are you using **fail2ban**'s ufw action and what value has `<insertpos>` in it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the built-in `ufw` action and `insertpost is `1` IPv6 was just a guess. I asked a network specialist and he said it's almost imposibble that tha attacker uses IPv6 but IPv4 get's logged.

Answer (score 1):

> But as you see the IP is already banned and the attacker still can access.

This issue is similar https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2545

Shortly: keep-alive vs. ufw (so I suggest don't use it, or extend an action to kill a connection).

> But why I don't get an IPv6 log entry then?

There are 2 reasons:

- either your fail2ban version <= 0.9 (IPv6 support got first time implemented in 0.10);
- or the logged message looks a bit different for IPv6, so failregex doesn't match that anymore (rewrite failregex compatible for both families);

#### UPD 1:

- either (better) place the rule for established connections after chain with fail2ban rules, or simply remove the rule whitelistening established connection;
- or you can use something like this to kill all established connection from IP to both local http/https ports:

```sh
ss -o state established -K dst $ip 'sport = 80 or sport = 443'
```

Note this expecting modern kernel (version >= 4.9 I suppose).
You can also add it directly in jail.local (without creating new local action config-file):

```
[some-nginx-jail]
_killstmt = ss -o state established -K dst <ip> 'sport = 80 or sport = 443'
banaction = %(known/banaction)s[actionban="<known/actionban><br>%(_killstmt)s"]
```

- or force nginx to close the connection by failed authentication (e. g. use own 40x location with `keepalive_timeout 0;`, which can also write an error into different log-file in order to avoid "parasite" traffic in sense of fail2ban, see [fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic) for more info);
  or simply make `return 444;` in corresponding location, that will cause a close the connection (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return for documentation)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you point out in your answer how to change the ufw action to kill connections, too?

Comment: Well, there are several possibilities, I've updated my answer (see UPD1 above).

Comment: forgotten still one possibility to close connect in nginx (make "return 444;", see at end of UPD1).

Answer (score 1):

As @sebres pointed out (Thanks a lot!!), keep alive connections are the cause for this behavior.

You can limit the number of keepalive requests in nginx.

Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add

```
keepalive_timeout 20; # this was already here but set to 65. 
keepalive_requests 20;
```

in the `http` section.

This should limit the keepalive connections to 20s and 20 requests per connection.

There should be similar rules for Apache.

Additional, you can also add [these rules](https://florent.clairambault.fr/limiting-number-of-connections-per-ip-with-ufw/) to ufw. Advantage is then that you can use these rules on any port you want. But most of these attack scripts use port 80 and 443.

I'm not sure if these rules could lead to problems!

Answer (score 1):

As @sebres remarked in his answer, this behaviour must be cause by `HTTP Keep-Alive`. If you want **fail2ban** to block requests from the remote client immediately can add a user-defined chain (e.g. `before-established`) to your iptables and place it just before the `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` rule in chain `ufw-before-input` (run `iptables -nv --line-numbers ufw-before-input` to list them):

```
iptables -N before-established
iptables -I ufw-before-input <desired_position> -p tcp --dport 80 -j before-established
```

and do the same for `ip6tables`. If you stop UFW, the rules should end up in `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and be reestablished between UFW restarts. Otherwise add the two lines manually (`iptables-save -t ufw-before-input` for the syntax).

To use the new chain with **fail2ban** you can create a new action file in `/etc/fail2ban/action.d` (let's call it `before-established.conf`) with the following content:

```
[INCLUDES]

before = iptables-common.conf

[Definition]

blocktype = DROP

actionflush = <iptables> -F before-established

actionstart = <actionflush>

actionstop = <actionflush>

actioncheck = <iptables> -n -L before-established >/dev/null

actionban = <iptables> -I before-established 1 -s <ip> -j DROP

actionunban = <iptables> -D before-established -s <ip> -j DROP

[Init]
```

and use this action instead of the **ufw** one.