# ufw deny from ip doesn't work

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, ufw

I know that I should setup fail2ban but at the moment I want to deny access from one IP address and tried the following ufw command:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from xx.xx.xx.xx to any
```

Here's the output of ufw status (with the ip blocked out):

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        xx.xx.xx.xx
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
```

I see the rule has been added and the firewall is active, but I'm still seeing connection from that ip:

```
netstat -natp | grep xx.xx.xx.xx
```

returns:

```
tcp        0  92672 yy.yy.yy.yy:443       xx.xx.xx.xx:32988    ESTABLISHED -
```

I've also tried to reboot the server with no luck.

What else could I check/try please?

Answer (score 0):

Fail2ban would also not help you if your firewall/net-filter sub-system doesn't work properly (just because it would also use that by banning).

Back to the question - you should check your ufw configuration (also in low-level filter, so its backend iptables/nftables).
See https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2545#issuecomment-543347684 for an example.

For instance, if you have some white-listing rules for established connections (default on some systems!), adding a new ufw-rule may not work for that, so you have:

- either to reject/drop such established connections additionally (e. g. using `tcpkill`, `ss -K` or `cutter`)
- or to remove completely this (probably low-level) rule for established connections, or to set its precedence low (move it below your rules/chain).
- or "ban" it using low-level modules (iptables/nftables) within chain before ufw rule allowing established connections.

Also note answer to similar questions:

- https://serverfault.com/a/1013516/488604
- https://serverfault.com/a/998163/488604